# SPI has turned on DMA but has been unable to get out of the loop

Tags: c, stm32, spi, dma

```
static HAL_StatusTypeDef SPI_Transmit(uint8_t* send_buf, uint16_t size)
{
//    return HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, send_buf, size, 100);
    HAL_StatusTypeDef state;
    
    state = HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi1, send_buf, size);
    while(hdma_spi1_tx.State != HAL_DMA_STATE_READY);
    return state;
}


static HAL_StatusTypeDef SPI_Receive(uint8_t* recv_buf, uint16_t size)
{
//   return HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, recv_buf, size, 100);
    HAL_StatusTypeDef state;
   
    state =  HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi1, recv_buf, size);
    while(hdma_spi1_rx.State != HAL_DMA_STATE_READY);
    return state;
}
```

I want to enable DMA for my SPI, but the breakpoint debugging "hdma_spi1_tx.State" has changed to "HAL_DMA_STATE_READY" during data transmission, but it still cannot jump out of the while loop. Why?

I have tried direct DMA transfer without waiting while, but the read data is wrong. For example, I am using a W25Q64 memory module, in

```
uint16_t W25QXX_ReadID(void)
{
    uint8_t recv_buf[2] = {0}; //recv_buf[0] stores Manufacture ID, recv_buf[1] stores Device ID
    uint16_t device_id;
    uint8_t send_data[4] = {ManufactDeviceID_CMD,0x00,0x00,0x00}; //data to be sent, command + address
    
    /* enable chip select */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(W25Q64_CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, W25Q64_CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    
    /* Send and read data */
    if (HAL_OK == SPI_Transmit(send_data, 4))
    {
        if (HAL_OK == SPI_Receive(recv_buf, 2))
        {
            device_id = (recv_buf[0] << 8) | recv_buf[1];
        }
    }
    
    /* cancel chip selection */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(W25Q64_CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, W25Q64_CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    
    return device_id;
}
```

But the read out is indeed 0x0000. It is reasonable to say that the device_id of W25Q64 should be 0XEF16. After checking the breakpoint debugging, something magical happened. The device_id was actually read out. After thinking about it for a while, the previous `while (hdma_spi1_tx.State != HAL_DMA_STATE_READY);` I have to wait all the time, but the result of waiting is that I can't get out of the loop

Comment: Please always add a language tag, and a tag for the MCU you're using. I guessed STM32, please [edit] if that's not the case.

Comment: Your SPI device probably starts transmitting as soon as it receives a command. Look into using `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()` to send and receive at the same time. If your plan is to use DMA then immediately poll for its completion, then there's no point using DMA. Just use the regular polling routines instead, which do that for you, and avoid needless complication.

Comment: Also, use `HAL_SPI_GetState()` to get the status of the SPI device, rather than accessing its internal state through other means.

Comment: oh! First of all, thank you very much @pmacfarlane .This solves my problem, just I want to ask is there any difference between 'HAL_SPI_GetState()' to get the state of SPI and which way I did before?

Comment: @KunBoy5240 Yes, calling an external function like `HAL_SPI_GetState()` means that it will definitely load the status flag, e.g. `hdma_spi1_tx.State` from RAM and test it. Your loops that access it directly may assume that the value never changes, unless it is declared as `volatile`.

Comment: I think I get it, thanks a lot @pmacfarlane

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. First off, SPI usually is full-duplex - both devices send and receive at the same time. Secondly, without going into details of particular sensor you are trying to communicate with, there are 2 types of devices:

1. Ones that can shift output right away, meaning you send "cmd_high" "cmd_low" "dummy data", where IC responds with "something" "something" "cmd_response" (where "something" is either status bytes or response for previous request). So you have to "send" "command_length" + "response_length" amount of SPI clocks. Maybe an extra dummy byte in between, to allow IC to load data into output register
2. Ones that require de-asserting chip-select pin between a request and response, so logic would be "assert_CS" -> "send request" -> "deassert_CS" -> "wait" -> "assert_cs" -> "read response" -> "deasseert_CS"

So, let's look at your code. You are sending 4 bytes (CMD_ID + 3 dummies) and expecting 2 bytes in return without de-asserting CS. This would imply, that your IC is of first type. Another hint is that you seem to get response with an extra delay introduced by your breakpoint.

I would suggest following things:

1. Make both RX/TX buffers same size. Since SPI is full-duplex, STM HAL library creates a dummy buffer for you in the background and uses effectively TransmitReceive() where stuff you are not interested in (RX buffer in Transmit and TX buffer in Receive) is discarded/faked. Having both buffers under your control and available for inspection will make your life easier.
2. Use HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive() function directly. Afterwards you can inspect both buffers. If there is no response in first attempt, try again, maybe there is data in the next response
3. *_DMA() functions in STM HAL require interrupt handlers for at least DMA stream, sometimes also for peripheral. Your hdma_spi1_tx.State is updated by these handlers (since they are just variables in a struct in memory). If you want to do polling checks, you'll have to poll the registers themselves
4. Normally you would have de-asserting CS and process signalling in your DMA_Done handler, that signals your CPU that operation is done. Having DMA with polling for result is useless, since whole point of DMA is to free CPU from dealing with peripheral data I/O management. If you are running bare metal, you can use a flag that signals your main task that processes data in a loop, occasionally checking for flag status.